# How to align upto 3 checkbox group values horizontal after than vertical in lightning?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

[image]

```
 <aura:attribute name="options" type="List" default="[
{'label': 'Nursery', 'value': 'option1'},{'label': 'KG1', 'value': 'option2'},{'label': 'KG2', 'value': 'option3'},
{'label': 'Class1', 'value': 'option4'},{'label': 'Class2', 'value': 'option5'},{'label': 'Class3', 'value': 'option6'},
 {'label': 'Class4', 'value': 'option7'} ,{'label': 'Class5', 'value': 'option8'},{'label': 'Class6', 'value': 'option9'},
  {'label': 'Class7', 'value': 'option10'},{'label': 'Class8', 'value': 'option11'},{'label': 'Class9', 'value': 'option12'} ,
   {'label': 'Class10', 'value': 'option13'},{'label': 'Class11', 'value': 'option14'},{'label': 'Class12', 'value': 'option15'}                                               
]"/>
<aura:attribute name="value" type="List" default="option1"/>
<lightning:checkboxGroup name="Checkbox Group"
                         label=""
                         options="{! v.options }"
                         value="{! v.value }"
                         onchange="{! c.handleChange }" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this

```
.THIS .slds-checkbox {
display: inline !important;
}
```

Comment: Hi @sdandamud1, I tried with this style and i am getting unexpected output i need only three checkbox should display in one line